# Add data from column in source table to new column in destination table

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a column organization in my source table and I need to add that same column into my destination table and I need to make sure it lines up with the correct AccountID. How can I do this in ssis after I have added the new "organization" column to my destination table?

Comment: Double click on OLE DB destination, go to Mapping Tab, and map the source column with destination column

Comment: @Hadi how will it know what organization goes with which account ID? Currently I have AccountID in both my source and destination table. I have added a column to my destination table in ssms to match the organization column in my source table. What I want to accomplish is to get the data in the organization source column and load it into the new organization column in my destination table. I also want to make sure it matches the correct ID.

Comment: Even after your comment, your question is still unclear. Try using data examples. Source data to current results to desired results.